# VueJS getting the page to accept UID & token

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, django-rest-framework, vuejs2, django-templates

I'm trying to get an activation link from an email to successfully pass it's UID and token to a vue page where it'll get authenticated.

I have my folder structure set up currently like .../registration/activate/_uid/_token.vue, but that causes the registration link to bring up a 404 page.

I've tried setting up to /_uid/_token/_token.vue with the extra token to see what'll happen, and it lets token.vue render, but I don't think the params are being passed. I'm also getting a "Duplicate param keys in route with path: "/registration/activate/:uid?/:token?/:token?" error in console.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card v-if="status === 'pending'" class="pa-8 text-center">
      <p class="title">Please wait</p>
      <p class="body-1">Checking registration status...</p>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-if="status === 'success'" class="pa-8 text-center">
      <p class="title primary--text">Activation successful</p>
      <p class="body-1">You may now log in.</p>
      <v-btn color="primary" text @click="navigateToLogin">Log In</v-btn>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-if="status === 'error'" class="pa-8 text-center">
      <p class="title error--text">Invalid activation token</p>
      <p class="body-1">This token is invalid. Please try again.</p>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  auth: false,
  data: () => ({
    status: 'pending'
  }),
  mounted() {
    
    this.$axios
    
      .post('/auth/users/activation/', this.$route.params)
      .then((response) => {
        this.status = 'success'
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.status = 'error'
      })
  },
  methods: {
    navigateToLogin() {
      this.$router.push('/login')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's an example of a registration link.

http://localhost:3000/activate/MTg/5j2-d0af1770a53f1db2a851

Another part of issue that I can't quite solve, is since I'm using python for my backend should I use a python template to submit the UID and token or figure out a way to send the email where the root is localhost:3000 (my frontend) vs :8000 (my backend).

Currently my settings.py looks like this for the registration link:

```
 'ACTIVATION_URL': 'registration/activate/{uid}/{token}',
```

the root is localhost:8000 for the whole API. So if I can't figure out how to manually set it to 3000 for just this link, I guess I'll need to use a template right? Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is your path declaration. In Vue you should declare a param in path like this:

```
 path: "/registration/activate/:uid/:token"
```

after this if you enter `http://localhost:3000/activate/MTg/5j2-d0af1770a53f1db2a851` your `this.$route.params` should look like this:

```
{"uid":"MTg","token":"5j2-d0af1770a53f1db2a851"}
```

and you axios request is fine.

and because yout are sending a JSON to server if your using django you can use this code to get the body of a request:

```
def avtivate(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'Raw Data: "%s"' % request.body   
  return HttpResponse("OK")
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I just needed the path params and the authentication worked :)